# Delay Vuelidate validation until data fetched from remote API

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I have added Vuelidate to my Quasar 2 application with a very simple `required` validation on an input field. The validation itself works fine but here's my problem:

The component's fetches some data from an API in its `onMounted` function. This data is used to initially populate the form. For the time loading, however, the input field is evaluated as `invalid`. Only once data have arrived, the input field becomes valid.

Is it possible to start the validation only once the API call has finished?

Please see the following example on Codesandbox which "simulates" the loading process by adding a timeout of 5 seconds:

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-fast-h7ld0c?file=/src/pages/Index.vue

Comment: I briefly look at these lib docs. I see there are option to create [async validators](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/custom_validators.html#async-validators), have you tried to use it? It might be necessary to build some custom async validator in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `v-model` attribute to use that of Vuelidate and, additionally, use the `$error` property instead of `$invalid`.

```html
<q-input
  v-model="v$.title.$model"
  :error="v$.title.$error"
/>
```

This seems to work, that is, the field is initially validated until the data have been fetched. If the user then clears the field, it becomes invalid.

https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-forest-7u0916?file=/src/pages/Index.vue

Answer (score 1):

This is a case for async validation.

I had a similar need to yours: in my situation, selecting a value from one dropdown would trigger an HTTP request to dynamically populate options in another dropdown. My validation condition was that the selected value in the second dropdown needed to match one of its dynamic options.

In your case, you should be using `helpers.withAsync()` to tell Vuelidate to await the results of the backend call before applying validation. This helper is pretty intuitive in the case that your async validator function *returns a validation result*, i.e. the user inputs a value and you make a request with that value to some endpoint that returns `true` or `false`.

It's less intuitive in your case, because the async operation you're awaiting is returning a value *that you need to apply validation against*, not the result of the validation itself.

Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-leaf-6ld23p?file=/src/App.vue) I created to explore this scenario. You'll want to look at Case 2 and Case 3.

In Case 3, specifically, is where I'm mocking a call to the backend to fetch new dropdown options. The validator method that's applied in Case 3 is called `asyncIncludes()`, and this is where things get a little tricky.

Because my validation relies on a backend call, but the backend call doesn't return the validation result itself, I had store the promise returned by the `mockFetch()` in a variable and instruct Vuelidate to watch that binding and re-fire the validation when its value changes.

In order to watch a reactive value within a Vuelidate validator, the library requires wrapping the the validator function in `helpers.withParams()`. This automatically necessitates writing the validator as a higher order function, which accepts a param as argument (in this case the promise) and returns a validator function.

Then, within `helpers.withParams()`, I provide an async validator wrapped in `helpers.withAsync()` to await the result of the promise passed to `asyncIncludes` before applying the validation.

The result is that anytime the respective HTTP call is fired, the resulting promise is stored in a variable watched by Vuelidate, which re-fires the validator. It just so happens that the validator is async and will wait for the promise to resolve before evaluating the validation condition and returning the result.

The `$error` property provided by Vuelidate is a a convenience property that represents `.$invalid`, `.$dirty` and `.$pending`. Async validators update `$pending` and Vuelidate will suspend the `$error` state while `$pending` is true (i.e. while your async operation is taking place).

Hope this helps!